# which classes/functions should Helper package typically contain - Selenium & cucumber

Tags: selenium, frameworks, cucumber

I have a Helper package in my selenium framework.

Can anyone help me with what classes or functions typically I should write in this package

Configuration: Selenium & cucumber

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Not related but if you put the `TestRunner` and features in `org.facebook.products` you don't need to configure glue or features in `CucumberOptions`.

Comment: but if I add features folder in org.facebook.products ,. shows up error as feature files are not java class files ,. only java related files are allowed inside of java folder ,. so I moved them to resources

Comment: You can use the same path in the resources folder `org/facebook/products`

Comment: And check your target or build folder. You'll see that test features and classes and up in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

I typically keep the classes those contain generic things but  will be helpful occassionally. For example, Dictionary that will contain locator details in case you are not using page factory. You can add Thread handling class, wait handling class and loggers/report handing.